# Split/Tile A3 (landscape) pdf to A4 (portrait)

Tags: pdf

How can I easily convert/split/tile every page of an PDF file which is A3/landscape to A4/portrait?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**command line solution**

1. Install pdfposter

   `sudo apt-get install pdfposter`
2. Use pdfposter

   `pdfposter path/to/input.pdf path/to/output_splitted.pdf -m a4 -p 2x1a4`

Comment: Very nice. An overlap or page margin would be nice, to accommodate non-printable page borders, but pdfposter doesn't seem to support this without hacking (maybe you can hack it with a fake page size...). My solution to this problem was to print the output PDF slightly scaled down. But then you still have to cut it very precisely.

Comment: There is a patch adding `--overlap-percent` option here: https://gitlab.com/pdftools/pdfposter/-/issues/1

Comment: 10 years later and this is still *exactly* what I needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
mutool poster -x 2 input.pdf output.pdf
```

Installation in Debian 10/Buster:

```
apt install mupdf-tools
```

For reordering the pages after splitting, you can use `pdftk`.

Comment: Is there a way to make `mutool` add a margin around the printable area of the page?

Answer (score 0):

**GUI solution**

If the dimension (A4 instead of A3) is not important (as this is not important for viewing the file and can be easily adjusted while printing), you can use [PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/) (open source) which allows to **rotate** pages.

[image: PDFsam overview]